# How to debug networking react native ios with firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger, flipper

I using react-native version 0.72.5 and @react-native-firebase/app 18.

when I config in Podfile, I add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` and comment

```
# :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
# :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
# :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
```

I cannot use react-native-debugger and can only use flipper but networking is unavailable. How to debug it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `flipper_configuration => flipper_config` does some changes related to the `Network Plugin Setup`.
You will need to add it manually, as follows:

To your `podfile`, add this:

```
pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', '~>' + flipperkit_version
```

Then, initialize the plugin, by adding into your `AppDelegate.m`:

If it uses Objective-C:

```objectivec
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>

[[FlipperClient sharedClient] addPlugin: [[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
```

If it uses Swift:

```swift
import FlipperKit

client?.add(FlipperKitNetworkPlugin(networkAdapter: SKIOSNetworkAdapter()))
```

This should work for IOS.

You can read more about it and how to do it on Android on [this](https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/plugins/network/) page on the docs.

Comment: What is flipperkit_version? I tried with the current version on my mac which is 0.236.0 but there is a warning when pod install is: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin":
  In Podfile:
    FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin (~> 0.236.0)

Comment: i tried the documentation [here](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-ios/) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    # :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => false,
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug"], { 'Flipper' => '0.163.0' }),
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseSessions', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :modular_headers => true
```

My podfile config, hope this help you

Comment: I'm pod install success, but when I build it
ERROR: 'FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h' file not found